# CSS resize handle and mouse event in Chrome

Tags: css

Playing around with the `resize` property of CSS, I stumbled upon this problem. I have a div which contain a canvas.

```css
.resizable {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

In this configuration with Chrome 76, the div can't be resized. Dragging the resize handle does nothing. (It works with Firefox)

If I disable `pointer-events` on the canvas or if I make the canvas smaller, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/t085nv9r/.

I guess it is because the canvas is masking the handle when it's size is set to 100% of the parent. However, my understanding is that the event are supposed to bubble up to the parent so whatever event the canvas is catching (if there is not stopPropagation) the div is supposed to receive it too and the resize shall happen.

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Setting overflow to `scroll` adds scroll bars to the div which makes the canvas not covering the whole div and the handle is working OK. But this not a solution for me. I would rather not have useless scroll bar in my div.

Comment: The event is probably `on resize` but to start it, you have to set it also on your canvas. And it will probably not be propagate to parent.. I think the best is to add handle the event on the canvas and with Javascript to update the parent size. (Or even add a small div on the bottom/right and create yourself a resizable event based on `ondragstart`/`onmousemove`/`ondragend`

Comment: Also please use the internal code snippet instead of using external website like jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: The resizing works in both of your fiddles in FireFox.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work in Firefox. I'll update my question.

Comment: in the duplicate there is a solution without decreasing the size or adding pointer-events

Comment: This is not a solution but a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

could try something like this:

```
canvas {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what this does, it will of course work. What I am trying to do is to have the canvas cover the whole div.